# Why doesn't the dart2js compiler convert 64-bit integers to IEEE 754 FP numbers?

Tags: javascript, integer, dart, precision

I've been reading that the dart2js compiler doesn't support 64 bit integers. Is this because javascript doesn't have a representation for 64-bit integers and stores all numbers as 64-bit double precision values? If so, couldn't integer values simply be converted to the representation? If that is not the case, why doesn't the compiler support this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because JS doesn't have 64 int. I'm not sure what you mean by the rest of your question. If you store bigger values as double, you loose precision.

Comment: Whoops, I think I confused myself with my understanding of machine numbers. I had forgotten that an integer doesn't utilize a mantissa, exponent bits and a sign bit whereas a floating point number does.